# Eclipse Oxygen tarda en iniciar

Tags: eclipse-oxygen

Mi problema es el que comento en el propio título.

Tengo el Eclipse **Oxygen** instalado, concretamente la versión `eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64.zip` y el problema es que una vez que descomprimo el paquete e inicio el programa, ahí se queda en el pantalla de inicio (la anterior a la que aparece cuando te dice que indiques el workspace).

Ayer funcionaba perfectamente, y el único cambio que hice fue intentar instalar el **plugin** `Spring Tools Suite`, no pude hacerlo ya que no sé por qué no puedo instalar ningún plugin desde el `marketplace` sin que me salte un error. Lo configuré en otro pc, descargándolo desde la página oficial y me va perfectamente y puedo instalar plugins sin problema.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es el plugin instalado, ve a Help -> Eclipse MarketPlace -> Installed, selecciona el plugin del problema y dale uninstall, le das en aceptar y cuando finalice reinicias ecplipse, en caso que te de error ya muy a la fuerza ve a la carpeta "plugins" y elimina el que te esta causando problemas.

si instalaste desde repositorio deberas desinstalarlo en Help -> Install New Software, ahi te aparece una ventana que dice already instaled como vinvulo, le picas ahi y te mandara a una lista donde podras buscar el plugin y darle uninstall, igualmente deberas reiniciar eclipse :)

Espero que eso resuelva tu problema.